# model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Boolean', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.checkboxstate'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I have a custom html helper with the last parameter as bool type. My code works fine when there is data in the database. But, without data, it throws following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Then, I tried to check for the possible 'null value' and send the value as 'false' to the view, apparently, without success.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    bool? defaultVal = true;

    var dbValue = context.checkboxstates.Where(c => c.Name == "Country").FirstOrDefault();
    if (dbValue == null)
    {
        return View(defaultVal);
    }               
    return View(dbValue);
}
```

My View:

```
@model MyProject.CheckboxState
@Html.MyCustomHtmlHelper("text", "AnotherText", "changeState", Model.state)
```

Here, Model.state is responsible for 'checking' checkbox 'checked' or 'unchecked' based upon the value returned from database. I do not have a model as I'm using database first approach.

If I try to pass explicitly a boolean value from the controller, I get this error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Boolean', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MyProject.checkboxstate'.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to mark the question as "SOLVED", but the correct approach is to accept one of the answers. This will remove the question automatically from the "unanswered" view. It also, and perhaps most importantly, gives credit to the person who helped you get there.

Comment: Couldn't see the choose answer tab. Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `Model` is `null` try passing a default value to your custom html helper:

```
@Html.MyCustomHtmlHelper("text", "AnotherText", "changeState", Model!=null?Model.state:false)
```

You can't pass a boolean parameter to your view due to it's expecting an object of `CheckboxState` type as model.

Comment: @rkun: don't forget to accept this answer when the system allows you to do so. To accept an answer, click the tick mark to the left of the answer you prefer, so that it turns green. This is how we thank helpful people in Stack Overflow.